# I want to add an extra implementation method to the trait and make the struct callable

Tags: rust, traits

I want to add an extra implementation method to the trait and make the struct callable, but I don't know how to implement.

I don't know what title is better for my problem.

example:

```rust
pub struct A {}

impl A {
  pub fn main(self){

    let boxed: Box<A> = Box::new(self);
    boxed.test(); // method not found in `Box<A>`
    // expect working

    let boxed: Box<dyn Trait> = boxed;
    boxed.test(); // working

  }
}

pub trait Trait {
  fn whatever(&self) -> u32
}

impl Trait for A {
    fn whatever(&self) -> u32 { unimplemented!() }
}

impl dyn Trait {
  pub fn test(&self) {
    unimplemented!()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put the extra method in a new trait and implement that trait (`Test`) for all types that implement the other trait (`Trait`):

```rust
pub struct A {}

impl A {
  pub fn main(self){

    let boxed: Box<A> = Box::new(self);
    boxed.test();

    let boxed: Box<dyn Test> = boxed;
    boxed.test();

  }
}

pub trait Trait {
  fn whatever(&self) -> u32;
}

impl Trait for A {
    fn whatever(&self) -> u32 { unimplemented!() }
}

pub trait Test {
  fn test(&self);
}

impl<T> Test for T where T: Trait + Sized {
  fn test(&self) {
    unimplemented!()
  }
}

fn main() {
}
```

And if you want to inherit the functionality of `Trait` in `Test`, you can introduce a respective trait bound:

```rust
pub struct A {}

impl A {
  pub fn main(self){

    let boxed: Box<A> = Box::new(self);
    boxed.test();

    let boxed: Box<dyn Test> = boxed;
    boxed.test();
    boxed.whatever();
  }
}

pub trait Trait {
  fn whatever(&self) -> u32;
}

impl Trait for A {
    fn whatever(&self) -> u32 { unimplemented!() }
}

pub trait Test: Trait {
  fn test(&self);
}

impl<T> Test for T where T: Trait + Sized {
  fn test(&self) {
    unimplemented!()
  }
}

fn main() {
}
```